# About a pair of vectors and the value of its sum norm

Tags: analytic-geometry

Knowing that |u|=11, |v|=23 and |u-v|=30 how can i calculate |u+v| (where || denotes the norm of a vector)?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: The [Parallelogram Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) states that $\|u+v\|^2 + \|u-v\|^2 = 2\|u\|^2+2\|v\|^2$.